# Split a string with repeating pattern, retaining delimiter

Tags: php, regex, split

Let's say we have a command parser input whereby a given character (a dot in this case) serves two functions: to split up strings into other commands and also to instruct the parser to repeat the last command.

For example:

```
go north.pick up item.go west...go north..
```

What this would achieve is "go north, pick up item, go west three times, go north twice". However, when using `preg_split` I simply cannot get the desired output.

All I have up to now is:

```
$temp = 'go north.pick up item.go west...go north..';
preg_split('/\.)/', $temp);
```

which yields:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => go north
>       [1] => pick up item
>       [2] => go west
>       [3] =>
>       [4] =>
>       [5] => go north
>       [6] =>
>       [7] =>
>   )

This is obviously incorrect in two instances - no dots returned and an extra command at the end. The dots must be returned so our parser can work out the user wants to repeat their last command.

Using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` does not fare any better, despite using `(\.)` as the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~([^.]+)(\.+)~', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    // $match[1] is what to do and $match[2] contains the dots.
    echo 'Do ', $match[1], ' ', strlen($match[2]), ' times', "\n";
}
```

See [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$temp = 'go north.pick up item.go west...go north..';
preg_match_all('/[^.]*\./', $temp, $r);
var_dump($r);
```

See http://ideone.com/a7o7v for a demonstration of the output.